# Cross-section of pair creation via vitual photons not positive definite

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, virtual-particles, scattering-cross-section, pair-production

Consider the process of pair creation via two virtual photons, i.e. $\gamma^*(k_1)+\gamma^*(k_2) \rightarrow l^-(p_1)+l^+(p_2)$, where the dilepton (or any other fermions) can be massless or massive, but the photons carry a non-zero virtuality, i.e. $k^2<0$.
This can be thought of as the time inverse pair annihilation process given in Peskin & Schroeder 1995 (pg. 168).
The amplitude matrix element for the two channels would sum to something like this:

$$i\mathcal{M}=-ie^2\epsilon_\mu(k_1)\epsilon_\alpha(k_2) \bar{u}(p_1)\left[\gamma^\mu\frac{q_t+m_l}{q_t^2-m_l^2}\gamma^\alpha+\gamma^\alpha\frac{q_u+m_l}{q_u^2-m_l^2}\gamma^\mu\right]v(p_2)$$

The $q$ in the numerator should be a slashed notation. This is for 2-to-2 tree level leading order diagram, with the following kinematics:

\begin{align}
-k_1^2&=Q_1^2\\
-k_2^2&=Q_2^2\\
p_1&=p_2=m_l^2\\
s&=(p_1+p_2)^2=2m_l^2+2p_1\cdot p_2\\
&=(k_1+k_2)^2=-Q_1^2-Q_2^2+2k_1\cdot k_2\\
t&=(p_1-k_1)^2=(k_2-p_2)^2\equiv q_t^2\\
u&=(p_1-k_2)^2=(k_1-p_2)^2\equiv q_u^2.\\
\end{align}

Evaluating the amplitude square, using Feynman gauge for the photon polarization sum, evaluating the gamma matrices using *Mathematica*+*FeyCalc*, and taking the massless fermion limit, we get something like this:

$$
\left|\mathcal{M}\right|^2\sim 2e^4\left[\frac{tu-Q_1^2Q_2^2}{t^2}+\frac{tu-Q_1^2Q_2^2}{u^2}-\frac{2s(Q_1^2+Q_2^2)}{tu}\right]
$$

Which is not positive definite when the photon virtuality is large (actually not so large, just of order $\sqrt{s}/2$). Note $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are defined to be positive.
When we take the vanishing virtuality approximation, we recover the result of Peskin & Schroeder 1995 (pg. 571, eq. 17.72), and get something like this:

$$
\left|\mathcal{M}\right|^2\sim 2e^4\left(\frac{u}{t}+\frac{t}{u}\right).
$$

Here is what I don't understand, I know that cross-sections are usually positively defined (OK, sometime high order loop results are not positive), but why is this leading order cross-sections not positively defined?
Or does this only appear when the particles are massive?
Is there a theorem for this?
What other conditions are there that could result in a negative cross-section?
What Peskin & Schroeder did was taking the high energy massless limit already at the amplitude level, what happens when cross-sections are generalized to massive case?